# @stream-io The following error occurs when using it after installation : Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: reactjs, import, syntax, export, es6-modules

After the above error occurs

Even though you added "tyrp": "module" to package.json

`tsconfig.json "compilerOptions": { "module": "commonjs" }`

The module cannot be used for the above processing.
I think it's an error due to the use of typescript, is there a way to solve it?

typescript: export& import syntax error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.